# Ubuntu AMD graphics driver

Tags: graphics, 15.10, amd-processor

I'm using 15.10 Ubuntu on my HP laptop . It has an AMD graphics card (2GB).
I have posted the screenshot of my Additional driver .

Can you guys tell what do I have to install more ?

[image: Additonal driver screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

A proprietary driver is not installed.

You can install it by selecting it in Additional Drivers.

What is "AMD graphics driver(2GB)" is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

I have AMD integrated graphics (R5) in my laptop. I had problems when using open source drivers (glitches, some programs were crashing ex. OpenOffice crashed when I wanted to insert formula). If you notice something similar try installing proprietary drivers (fglrx). You can do this in System Settings -> Software -> Additional Drivers. Select fglrx, wait for it to download and restart the computer.